# Why Firefox caching work will reset in version 3 but version 16 don't?

Tags: web-development, web-browser, internet-explorer, firefox

I am developing a web application and have the app deployed into Tomcat server. Tested on IE and Firefox and are working fine. Meaning when I close the browser and reopen the app, the data will be reset. When deploy to Websphere, the data is reset only in IE but Firefox don't. Meaning Firefox will cache the old data. I did try to clear the cache in FF but still failed. I did a test in FF3 and FF16, FF3 will reset the value but FF16 doesn't, I am just so curious why this could happened?

Now I don't know whether this is my code problem or is actually the FF caching problem. Any clue on this?

Comment: ctrl-f5 will bypass the cache see if that works, also check the cache control headers you send

Comment: Did ctrl-f5, still failed.

Answer (score 3):

HTTP caching is quite complex and influenced by a number of HTTP headers, so there is ample room for misunderstanding and different interpretations of the standard. And the standard has been extended a few times. This explains why you're seeing different results with different browsers.

[This document](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#PRAGMA) explains it in detail. Read it, understand it, then look at what HTTP headers your application sends. If you still can't solve the problem, ask another question here that includes those HTTP headers.